# ¿como puedo capturar el llamado a la API en mi test de wdriverIO utilizando nock?

Tags: javascript, api, test, mocking

voy a dejar el it donde se supone que al hacer click en iniciar sesion deberia realizar la llamada desde el front y a su vez utilizo el nock para capturarla y mostrar en la consola la respuesta. El problema es que no intercepta la llamada.

```
it('Click en Login', async () => {
        AllureReporter.addDescription("Click en Login");
        AllureReporter.addSeverity('blocker');
    
        try {
            const scope = nock('https://ps.hdbet.betwarriorpam.com')
                .post('/ps/ips/login?brandId=8') // Asegúrate de usar el método POST y la URL correcta
                .reply(200, { data: 'response' });
    
        
            browser.pause(5000)

            // Hacer clic en el botón de inicio de sesión
            const iniciarSesionButton = await $('[data-testid="login-submit-button"]');
            await iniciarSesionButton.click();
    
            // Verifica si se ha interceptado la llamada a la API
            const isApiIntercepted = nock.isDone();
    
            if (isApiIntercepted) {
                // Puedes imprimir la respuesta en formato de texto en la consola.
                console.log(`Response Body: ${JSON.stringify({ data: 'example' })}`);
                console.log(`isApiIntercepted: ${isApiIntercepted}`);
            } else {
                console.error("La llamada a la API no se interceptó.");
                console.log(`isApiIntercepted: ${isApiIntercepted}`);
            }
    
            after(() => {
                nock.restore();
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error durante la ejecución de la prueba:', error);
        }
    });
```

**Esta es la llamada que deberia captar:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obviamente el codigo es mas amplio, es un:

```
 describe('Login BW City - with valid credentials', () => {
}
```

contiene muchos mas it antes de llegar al de hacer click que se muestra arriba.

Respuesta en la terminal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]